# Sequelize findAll() throwing error when including associations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm pretty new to Sequelize and trying to learn all of the cool tricks you can use to format your queries, but have run into a bit of a wall.

Basically I have a table "invoices". I have another table "invoice_items" which has a relationship many invoice_items to one invoice.

Currently I am trying to include this one to many association in a findAll query such that the invoice_items are nested in an array in each invoice object.

Something along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    name: invoice1
    invoiceItems: [
      itemOne,
      itemTwo,
    ]
  },
    {
    name: invoice2
    invoiceItems: [
      itemOne,
      itemTwo,
    ]
  }
]
```

When I try this query (essentially grabbed from the documentation)

```
db.invoice.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: 'ed8fdd40-b807-4e51-b1f5-90fb5b7f6e73'
    },
    include: { all: true, nested: true }
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

I am met with an error

```
c:\Users\brend\Desktop\projects\invoice-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1189
          let associations = result.get(include.association.as);
                                    ^

TypeError: result.get is not a function
    at c:\Users\brend\Desktop\projects\invoice-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1189:37
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at c:\Users\brend\Desktop\projects\invoice-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1188:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Model._findSeparate (c:\Users\brend\Desktop\projects\invoice-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1186:39)
    at invoice.findAll (c:\Users\brend\Desktop\projects\invoice-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1153:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.10.0
```

The odd thing is that when I try something like this the query succeeds, but is not formatted as intended (A separate invoice object for each associated invoiceItem)

```
db.invoice.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: 'ed8fdd40-b807-4e51-b1f5-90fb5b7f6e73'
    },
    include: "invoiceItems",
    raw : true ,
    nest : true
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

To aid in identifying the issue I will add more full code below (wondering if I have the associations messed up):

invoice model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize, DataType) => {
    const Invoice = sequelize.define('invoice', {
        id: {
         type: DataType.UUID,
         primaryKey: true
        },
        userId: {
         type: DataType.UUID,
         validate: {
            allowNull: false
         }
        },
        name: {
         type: DataType.STRING(150)
        }
//Additional fields left out here for simplicity
     },{
        underscored: true
     });
     Invoice.associate = models => {
      Invoice.hasMany(models.invoiceItem), {
         foreignKey: "invoiceId"
      }
      Invoice.belongsTo(models.user)
     };

     return Invoice
};
```

invoiceItem model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize, DataType) => {
    const InvoiceItem = sequelize.define('invoiceItem', {
        id: {
         type: DataType.UUID,
         primaryKey: true
        },
        invoiceId: {
         type: DataType.UUID,
         validate: {
            allowNull: false
         }
        },
        userId: {
         type: DataType.UUID,
         validate: {
            allowNull: false
         }
        },
        name: {
         type: DataType.STRING(150)
        }
//Additional fields left out here for simplicity
     },{
        underscored: true
     });
     InvoiceItem.associate = models => {
      InvoiceItem.belongsTo(models.invoice, {
         foreignKey: "invoiceId"
      })
      InvoiceItem.belongsTo(models.user), {
         foreignKey: "userId"
      }};

     return InvoiceItem
};
```

And finally my index.js file that brings everything together

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const sequelize = require('../config/database.js')

const db = {}
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize, db.Sequelize.DataTypes)
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `include: { all: true }`?

Comment: @Anatoly Hi, thanks. Yes I did try that, unfortunately it seems to be the bit causing the error.

Comment: Well in the end I was able to eliminate the error by removing raw: true from the query defaults when I first made the new sequelize instance (which is a bit annoying, but not sure of any other work around). I still haven't achieved the desired output, but I have posted a simplified question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937468/how-to-get-associations-in-an-array-using-sequelize-findall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to eliminate the error by removing raw: true from the query defaults when I first made the new sequelize instance. Part of the problem seems to be that raw: true work with eager loading. I was then able to use the get() method to unwrap the results into my desired format. More details on the formatting can be found at my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937468/how-to-get-associations-in-an-array-using-sequelize-findall) in case someone finds it helpful at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup appears to be correct so far and the issue might be coming from the options you have specified (nested: true):

```
db.invoice.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: 'ed8fdd40-b807-4e51-b1f5-90fb5b7f6e73'
    },
    include: { all: true, nested: true } <------ begin by removing nested: true
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

In the above code, start by removing: nested: true, other options you can look at are plain: true, raw: true etc